# Customizing JPopupMenu in JFileChooser: Accessing Internal Components

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, jpopupmenu

[image]

How can I access the `JPopupMenu` that is invoked from a `JFileChooser` and customize that (background, foreground, borders)? The issue is that the popup is created inside `sun.swing.FilePane`, which I cannot access because the `sun.*` packages are not accessible by default. Developing a new `FileChooser` is not feasible as a lot of work has already been done.
Do you have any ideas?

I tried iterating through nested components, but since I couldn't import `FilePane`, it didn't yield any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried iterating through nested components, but since I couldn't import FilePane, it didn't yield any results.

`sun.swing.FilePane` extends `JPanel`, you can search this `JPanel` instead and get the `JPopupMenu`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileChooserPopupMenuTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      descendants(chooser)
          .filter(JPanel.class::isInstance)
          .map(c -> ((JPanel) c).getComponentPopupMenu())
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .findFirst()
          .ifPresent(popup -> {
            popup.addSeparator();
            popup.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("JCheckBoxMenuItem"));
          });
      chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    });
  }

  public static Stream<Component> descendants(Container parent) {
    return Stream.of(parent.getComponents())
        .filter(Container.class::isInstance)
        .map(Container.class::cast)
        .flatMap(c -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(c), descendants(c)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've moved past the stalemate.